# Are propellers dangerous?

Tags: quadcopter

Aren't all propellers super dangerous? How are these startups like Hex and Pocket Drone selling drones as 'kid-friendly' to consumers? What happens if a kid puts his finger in a propeller's movement space while its flying?

Comment: Having sustained nasty cuts from plastic propellers of quadrotors spinning at considerably low RPM, I can assure you that Drones are not very safe around kids. Unless they have a proper feedback mechanism and control, like A.R.Drone 2.0, which stops spinning as soon as the props hit something. If you're building/programming your own drone, you have to veryyyyyyy  careful.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they are dangerous. I've cut myself multiple times. Once through the nail. The small toy helicopters are apparently some cause for increased eye injury, although [studies](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22846260) suggest the injuries are usually not severe. Larger helicopters though seem to have caused [fatal injuries](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2424072,00.asp) in the past.

Answer (score 3):

Small quads that use brushed pager motors aren't too bad.  Typical quads that used brushless motors easily cut through flesh.  These shots were from an RC Groups thread where people were submitting their accident pictures.  Be careful!

For some  truly gruesome pictures (amputated fingers, severed tendons, etc), you can see this French language thread: http://chrismeme11.over-blog.com/article-36258812.html

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Aren't all propellers super dangerous?

Depends on the RPM and propeller size. Low RPM with very small diameter, may just result in cuts or bruises.

> How are these startups like Hex and Pocket Drone selling drones as 'kid-friendly' to consumers?

Quads are not kid-friendly. Pocket drone uses collapsible propellers that may reduce the force of the impact, but it will hurt.

> [image]

Hex uses pretty small propellers which reduces the area around it in which it will be dangerous.

> What happens if a kid puts his finger in a propeller's movement space while its flying?

Nothing good. Quads are dangerous and need to be handled extremely carefully.

Answer (score 0):

Yeeeees!!!
They r very dangerous, I was building a quadcopter, when I finished I was calibrating the esc, during the process, you have to leave the transmitter throttle on max and press few buttons. My quad malfunctioned then went full throttle then attacked my wrist. It was millimetres away from my nerves and tendon. I am only 14 years old. For this accident, I went into surgery and I had 13 stitches!

To conclude, Propellors are extremely dangerous. THEY CAN KILL!!! Never misuse a drone.

Comment: ...and this why all the documentation on ESC calibration tells you to first remove your propellers.